# Pass struts form parameter in JMeter?

Tags: struts, jmeter

How to pass struts form parameters in Jmeter. I got in formation by using Regular Expression Extractor we can solve it but, i am not getting any information how?

Comment: Can you try clarifying your question please? Are you stating that you can extract values from a Struts form using Regular Expression Extractor, but don't know how to use the results?

Comment: public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {}

Comment: In the above mentioned method I want to pass parameter value to Actionform using Jmeter HTTP reques to perform the load testing.If I pass the parameter directly by adding the parameters in "send parameter directly" it is not taking

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is NOT to create the requests yourself ( if that's what your doing ), but instead use jmeter as a proxy to record your web app flow. The proxy recording session will take take of boring head parameteres that, in my opinion, are too tedious to add by hand. You can find how to set up the jmeter proxy mode [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server) and [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). You can't miss it.

good luck!